# Nginx allows for url that start with /# even though I allow access only to 1 path

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to restrict access to all url paths except for one. Here's how my `nginx.conf` (split into 2 files) looks:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    upstream promo {
        server localhost:82;
    }
        
    server {
        listen 82;
        location / {
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            return 200 "gangam style";
        }
    }
    # nginx is running on Windows machine
    include .\conf\promo.conf;
}

events {}
```

The file `.\conf\promo.conf` contains additional configs where I have my server running on port 81 and restrict access to any request with request path other than `/gateway*`. So both `/gatewayABC` `gateway/abc` `/gateway` would be considered valid:

```
server {
    listen 81;
                    
    if ($request_uri !~ ^/$|^/gateway) {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://promo;
    }
}
```

So here's the catch:

- Whenever I send get request to http://localhost:81/gateway or http://localhost:81/gateway/abc I do get `200` status (AS EXPECTED)
- When I send get request to http://localhost:81/hello I get `403` (AS EXPECTED)
- However, when I alter a little bit my last request to http://localhost:81/#/hello I do get `200` for some reason (NOT AS EXPECTED)

So what is the problem with my config unable to recognize # as invalid pattern?

Comment: The browser never sends the [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) to the server, so Nginx never sees it.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you. But why does the condition with `$request_uri !~ ^/$|^/gateway` is not triggered in this case?

Comment: `/#/hello` is received as `/`, which matches `^/$`. Check the Nginx access log.